# How can I reduce the memory used by individual frontend appengine instances?

Tags: google-app-engine

Over the past year, it seems the amount of memory used by my frontend instances has gradually increased until it got to a point where I needed to start using F2 instances. Now even F2 memory (256 megs) is becoming a bit tight.

Why could this be happening? I'm not storing any data on the frontend instance memory itself. The codebase is getting bigger but not incredibly. There is much less than 100 classes in the entire project. I use memcache and datastore for all memory-related operations. What is eating up my memory?

Comment: What about the load? Do you have more users per instance? A larger number of requests running in parallel will consume more memory.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin no not really, sometimes as few as 5-10 users but the memory never really goes down. I do have the odd spike with up to a few hundred users (mostly landing page hits).

Comment: I have apps on App Engine with thousands of classes that happily work in the smallest instances. So something is off. How does your memory usage graph look? Is it gradually increasing, or it bumps into 200MB territory right away?

Comment: They seem to get there gradually: http://i.imgur.com/MfFNhBT.jpg
You can see here they've all been freshly restarted fairly recently (within the hour), so not bad now, but it does get up as high as 200 these days.

Comment: If it grows gradually, it looks like a memory leak - some resources are not closed/release/garbage-collected, so the memory use keeps growing. I don't think it's App Engine-related issue - you would probably face it on any platform.

Comment: I figured as much, but how could this be if I'm not using any instance memory....... I am setting attributes on the request level and I have probably 2-3 set on the session level...

Is it possible the fact that I have so many sessions lingering in the database that they're eating up memory somehow?

Comment: Java is using instance memory, every servlet is using memory, etc. The most common source of leaks is resources (HTTP calls, etc.), which you are obviously using to process your requests. If you can share some code, possibly as a separate question, we can look at the ways to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ndb library? If yes check it's not leaking memory.

We've just found our app is leaking memory inside @ndb.tasklet.

And there are few known issues with it.

Comment: I'm not actually. This is a java project that uses the appengine core datastore and memcache api directly. I have written a wrapper for the API calls, but that wrapper doesn't use instance memory explicitly at all. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I see. There should be some good memory profiles for Java. Are you not able to get a snapshot and report on what is eating memory?

Comment: I've done some searches for a good live GAE memory profiler but I can't seem to find a good one for java..

Comment: Try to look into bringing you instance to Compute Engine and here you should be able to use whatever you want.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok:  You can run java code anywhere, including your own PC, and profile it. No need to switch platforms just for that purpose.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, right, I assume this already should done? There could be differences in DEV & LIVE environments as GAE dev server just emulates real GAE.